# Find $\angle{FPC}$: impossible question?

Tags: trigonometry, quadrilateral, angle

I was given this question by one of my friends:

> [image: tricky puzzle]
>
> Shape $ABCD$ is a parallelogram.
> $AE = EB$
> $BF = FC$
> Find $\angle{FPC}$.

but when I tried to solve it, I found it impossible without at least a side value. I disagree with myself, as I am finding an angle, and size doesn't matter. I did this with trigonometry:

$$(EP) = \frac{(BC) \sin(180 - 110)}{\sin(90)}$$

This is using The Law of Sines. Then:

$$\angle{EFP} = \cos^{-1}(\frac{(EF)^2 + (FP)^2 - (EP)}{2(EF)(FP)})$$

This is using The Law of Cosines. Since $(EF) = (FP)$, I simplified that to:

$$\angle{EFP} = \cos^{-1}(\frac{2(EF)^2 - (EP)}{2(EF)^2}) = $$
$$\angle{EFP} = \cos^{-1}(1 - \frac{(EP)}{2(EF)^2})$$

From there, I went to:

$$\angle{FPC} = \frac{\angle{EFP}}2$$

Here I stopped. I thought something was wrong, so I went here to ask. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Did I make a mistake in my calculations? Is this question even possible? Note: please don't criticize me. I'm only grade 8.

Comment: How do you know EF=FP?

Comment: @tatan because BF = FC, and shape ABCD is a parallelogram, so BC is straight.

Comment: So,what?How do you prove it?

Comment: EBF and FPC-these two triangles are not congruent..

Comment: @tatan since F is halfway from B to C, and BC is straight, (putting a new point between E and P and naming it G) then FG ⊥ EP. Triangle FGE would then be a reflection of triangle FPG, so then EF = FP.

Comment: The given data do not determine $\angle FPC$. You can translate the vertical line $C\vee D$ to the right, keeping the other sides of the parallelogram fixed,  and adjust the point $F$ accordingly. In this way the angle in question will become larger. – Maybe originally one more piece of information was given, e.g. $|EB|=|EF|$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter It seems you are right. I will ask my friend about this question and change it depending on what he says.

Answer (score 1):

There are two points I want to make.

(1) Your suggestion (about EF = PF) is correct. Your approach is correct too.

However, the proof can be slightly simplified by quoting the “intercept theorem”. It says:-

If BE // CP // FG, and F divides BC into two intercepts in the ratio BF : FC, then G will divide EP into two intercepts in the same ratio. That is, EG : GP = BF : FC.

Therefore, after constructing a line through F parallel to BE cutting EP at G, we have EG = GP because BF = FC.

Because $\angle FGP = \angle BEG = 90^0$, FG is actually the perpendicular bisector of EP. Thus, your argument about symmetry can continue.

(2) This problem has no solution.

[image]

The diagram above shows if we draw another parallelogram (AB’C’D) having the same characteristics as ABCD, $\angle FPC$ will not equal to $\angle F’P’C’$. This means that angle is NOT constant and is quite length (of $AB$, say) dependent.