# Follow-up to Find $\angle{FPC}$: impossible question?

Tags: trigonometry, quadrilateral, angle

I have asked my friend about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1463250/find-anglefpc-impossible-question), and he now replied that is was a rhombus, not a parallelogram. The question is now:

> [image: tricky puzzle]
>
> Shape $ABCD$ is a rhombus.
> $AE = EB$
> $BF = FC$
> Find $\angle{FPC}$.

Now it should be possible to solve. Here is what I did:

Since $ABCD$ is a rhombus, $AB = BC$, which means $EB = BF$, because $AE = EB$ and $BF = FC$. $EB = BF$ leads to $\angle{BEF} = \angle{EFB}$, and since we know that $\angle{EBF} = 70^{\circ}$, $\angle{BEF} = \frac{180 - 70}2$. Because $\angle{BEF} = \angle{FPC}$, the answer, $\angle{FPC}$, is $55^{\circ}$.

Wow, much easier. Now the question is: Is my proof/explanation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, but you haven't explained why $\angle BEF=\angle FPC$.

The key to this is that because $F$ is the midpoint of $BC$, point $F$ must lie directly below the midpoint of $EP$. So $\triangle EPF$ is isosceles with $\angle FEP = \angle EPF$.